# what is the alternative for taglist plugin in sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, todo

We use Sonar 4.3 and want to show the list of tags we have used in our code (e.g. TODO, FIXME,...)
In previous versions of sonar we have used the taglist-plugin, but the documentation [1] says its deprecated and does not mention any alternative/new solution for it.

Is this feature now integrated into the core or is there an new plugin for this? ...I can't find anything

[1] http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Taglist+Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose is to implement (in the core) a new feature that will cover the features of this taglist plugin. This is the upcoming concept of "Finding", and here's the ticket about it: [SONAR-3270](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3270)

Feel free to vote and watch for it.

Comment: I really don't care if it is in the core or a plugin - as there is no alternative for now I'll stick to the plugin. thanks for the hint, would be good to add this to the plugin docu page too